# Exclude from build in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have c++ project in my Eclipse with some files marked with "exclude resource from build". Is possible somehow export and then import these Excludes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excludes are stored in `.cproject`, so you can save/edit/etc this file to achieve what you want.

Comment: In the .cproject file, the <sourceEntries> section has an <entry> element which contains a list of the file exclusions.  You can easily copy/paste these into another .cproject file or manually edit this value.  But for files marked "Derived", they have their own individual <fileInfo> elements with unique ID numbers and toolchain details, so it isn't as easy to reuse these.